# Not Getting/Inserting Data

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

It doesn't receive data from Firebase and Angular not working. Structure of Firebase database:

```
mainBranch
   -> achild : "good"
```

What is wrong with these codes?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- Angular -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Firebase -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.4.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>

    <!-- AngularFire -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.2.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("app",["firebase"]);
        app.controller("myController",["$scope","$firebaseObject",function($scope,$firebaseObject){

            const rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("mainBranch");
            this.object = $firebaseObject(rootRef);

        }]);
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: "a.ref is not a function"

Comment: You're trying to use AngularFire 1.x with Firebase 3.x, which won't work. For a better time, use the combination in the official AngularFire documentation: https://github.com/firebase/angularfire#getting-started-with-firebase

Comment: I changed version and it worked.